# jquery show/hide div

Tags: jquery

I have the next jquery code:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // hides the slickbox as soon as the DOM is ready
        // (a little sooner than page load)
      $('#hidden').hide();

    });

    //<![CDATA[
    function ShowHide(){
        $('#hidden').fadeIn();
        $("#shopping-cart").animate({"height": "toggle"}, { duration: 550 });
    }
    //]]>

    </script>
```

I use the div#hidden to get a dark background over it (kind of lightbox background) and I'm showing the #shopping-cart div including some elements like table, input, etc. after make a click at a A.cart-buttom

```
<a href="#" title="" onClick="ShowHide(); return false;" class="cart-buttom">Cart</a>
```

After the user make a click at the A button, to show the cart, the div#hidden is showed. I'd like to know would I make if the user click outside of the div#shopping-cart or in the A link again the div#hidden is fadeOut.

Now after make a click at the A link start the animation of the div#shopping-cart but the div#hidden doesn't dissapear.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, let's remove that click handler from being inline, so your link becomes this:

```
<a href="#" class="cart-buttom">Cart</a>
```

Then your jQuery looks like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#hidden').hide().click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });      
  $("a.cart-buttom").click(function(e) {
    $('#hidden').animate({ opacity: "toggle" });
    $("#shopping-cart").animate({"height": "toggle"}, { duration: 550 });
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  $(document).click(function() {
    $('#hidden').fadeOut();
  });
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/68gYU/)

What we're doing here is taking advantage of [event bubbling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html), using [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) if a click comes from the `<a>` or `#hidden`, the event doesn't go anywhere (doesn't bubble up to `document`, as it normally would).  If a `click` from anywhere *else* gets to `document` then it does a [`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) on the element, the same goes for clicking on the "Cart" link again.

Comment: that's a great solution but maybe I didnt explain in a good way the case.

Now when the #shopping-cart is "open" and the #hidden div appear.. if you click anywhere over #shopping-cart the #hidden div makes the fadeOut and the #shopping-cart doesnt move. But I want when the user click anywhere except #shopping-cart start both of the events.

By the way, the <a> buttom is inside of the div#shopping-cart

Comment: @estorde - I'm still not 100% clear, take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/68gYU/1/ is that what you mean?

Comment: @Nick: it's not the thing I'd need. I'll try to explain it again. Take a look now at: http://jsfiddle.net/68gYU/19/
At the begging the #shopping cart should appear hidden on the top of the page. Then, when you make a click at a.cart-buttom the #shopping-cart move down, the <a> keep at the same relative position at his "father" #shopping cart and at the same time the div#hidden appears under this.
Then when if the user makes a click at the <a.cart-buttom> or anywhere in the background (except over #shopping-cart) the elements recover the original position and state.

Comment: @estorde - Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/68gYU/20/ ...is that getting closer?

Comment: we are getting close:
take a look:http://jsfiddle.net/68gYU/37/

click somewhere except "cart" link or over div#shopping cart. The div and the link will move up. This one should be the initial position.

Now if you click at the "Cart" link, the div#shopping cart, with the "cart" link come down and appear the div#hidden.
This is the action that should be start any time the user click at the "Cart" buttom.

Once the div#hidden is showed and the div#shopping cart and the "Cart" link is down, any click at the "Cart" link or anywhere except div#shopping cart should restart the initial position.

:)

Comment: It's almost perfect. Once you click at the "Cart" link the action is perfect, and the action to come to the initial state is perfect if you click anywhere except div#shopping-cart... but (always there is a but, sorry) I'd like when the user also click at the "Cart" link the action works... I know this link is include inside the #shopping-cart, but if in that step doesnt work seems like a bug...

do you have an email? I could send you the file and maybe you could check the action directly.

Comment: do you guess you could take a last look a your code?? in any case.. thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

If you want to toggle fading on click of the link, you can use [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/),

```
$("a.cart-buttom").toggle(function(){
  $('#hidden').fadeIn(); 
}, function() {
  $('#hidden').fadeOut(); 
})
```